# how can i use vb.net editor instead of vba in autocad?

Tags: vba, autocad

visual basic editor in autocad is very low level , i need a more capable editor .... like vb.net or visual studio editor.... is it a way to work on VS and define autocad object there and it output the result in autocad?

Comment: the version is a little bit old...i use autodesk map 2009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [this](http://exchange.autodesk.com/autocad/enu/online-help/browse#WS73099cc142f48755-5c83e7b1120018de8c0-2471.htm) for getting started with MS Visual Studio for developping AutoCAD. You can also find informations on migrating from VBA to VB.NET [here](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=770215#vbatonet).